# Extract highlighted text from PDF using iText

Tags: java, pdf, itext

I am trying to extract highlighted text from a PDF file. I managed to write this code but it is not able to extract the highlighted text. Any idea what is the issue? Or is there a better/ way to do it? Any other library that I can use?

Thanks

```java
public String getHighlightedText() {
        log.info("test");
        String highlightedText = "";
        String pdfFilePath = "test.pdf";
        PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(pdfFilePath);
        log.info("reader.getNumberOfPages(): {}", reader.getNumberOfPages());
        for (int i = 1; i <= reader.getNumberOfPages(); i++) {
            String pageText = PdfTextExtractor.getTextFromPage(reader, i);
            log.info("page text : {} ", pageText);

            PdfDictionary pageDict = reader.getPageN(i);
            log.info("pageDict : {}", pageDict);
            PdfArray annotsArray = pageDict.getAsArray(PdfName.ANNOTS);

            if (annotsArray == null) {
                continue;
            }

            for (int j = 0; j < annotsArray.size(); j++) {
                PdfDictionary annotDict = annotsArray.getAsDict(j);
                log.info("annotDict.toString() : {} ", annotDict.getAsString(PdfName.CONTENTS));
                if (PdfName.HIGHLIGHT.equals(annotDict.getAsName(PdfName.SUBTYPE))) {
                    PdfString text = annotDict.getAsString(PdfName.CONTENTS);
                    log.info("text : {}", text);
                }
            }
        }

        reader.close();


        return highlightedText;
    }
```

Comment: I've removed the pdfbox label because your question is primarly about itext. The highlighted text isn't part of the annotation (regardless what library you use). So what you need to search for in itext is a feature that extracts the PDF text within the area covered by the annotation.

Comment: In addition to what @Tilman has said: Are you sure the _highlighted_ text in your PDF is highlighted by means of an annotation? I ask because some tools don't use annotations at all but instead add the highlighted appearance into the page content stream as regular content, simply drawing some yellow rectangles here or there...